# Session persistence issue (FortiWeb, multiplexing)

Tags: session, cookies, coldfusion, load-balancing, session-state

I work for a smaller company and we are struggling through a problem with session persistence right now that I am fighting with.

Some people are multiplexing (as diagnosed by Fortinet very recently) their user's connections to the site and the FortiWeb is apparently only handling session persistence cookies to the user with the first request.  All subsequent users on the multiplexed connection "piggy back" onto that first user.  Once a new TCP connection is established, the first user again gets a cookie assigned and all subsequent users "piggy back" the new user.

The problem is that everyone that was piggy backing is likely (75% chance) switching servers each time this happens and ends up with a missing session and is forced to log in again.  As a result, the more users, the more prevalent, frequent, and damaging this becomes.

The vast majority of our users do not have an issue with this but we have a couple larger clients that are experiencing issues.  We have not been able to successfully reproduce this problem in-house.

Rough network information:

The datacenter we are in (SSAE16 audited) supplies us a pair of redundant links that connect to a Highly Available FortiGate (active/passive) pair, which connects to a HA pair of HP switches (active/active), that in turn connect to an HA pair of FortiWebs (active/passive) that do the load balancing (and attack detection/prevention).  We have two sites like this, one production, one DR.

The FortiWebs load balance in a round robin format to four web servers running ColdFusion with cookie based persistence.  We have used both their cookie injection method and their persistent cookie (reads a pre-existing cookie that we set) method.  The persistent cookie method helps but just seems to heighten the number of people that can use us before symptoms arise.

We have been working with Fortinet support, largely fruitlessly, for a quite a while now.  As an example, they tell us to have clients turn off multiplexing and end the conversation there.  The clients we have suggested that to have said they implemented the change and have not seen a difference.  Fortinet responds by saying they can't help configure another companies hardware and we get caught in the middle.  But the longer this goes on, the more problematic this becomes.  We have tried to put more pressure on this, with little to no success.

Some of my thoughts and options that we have been contemplating:

Short term:

- Switch to a CentOS proxy VM we used to use years ago (much less fully featured and we do not have full confirmation that this helps, but it is believed to, makes our failover scenarios far more manual)
- Use a dynamic DNS configuration to route only certain entities to a CentOS proxy (have to manually configure this with each entity)
- Get an outside expert involved again (we did, but they weren't able to help much as they weren't able to reproduce it and the multiplexing thing didn't come to light until very recently, part of why I am here and I am waiting for a call back from a consulting company we frequently use)
- Revert to one webserver (Not going to cope with load during peak hours) to make sure all sessions go to one webserver

Long term:

- Cluster the web servers to share session information (we have concerns with how this would impact memory and bandwidth, and how it would scale as we add more web servers)
- Switch to F5 load balancers (a lot of money, and until we try it we have no guarantee this will fix the issue.  If it did fix the issue the money would be worth it.)
- Leave sessions and go back to cookies (obviously very low attractiveness)
- Wait for Fortinet's feature request (they don't consider this a bug) to have an option to enforce persistence on every request (they are not moving on this at all, have not met about it in over a month)
- Switch to a private or hybrid cloud provider instead of operating our own hardware

What am I missing or what do you think we should do?